# For loop for defining index and len() in python

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Task 1 : Python’s `len(..)` function takes in a `string` or a `list`, and returns its length. Using the `len(..)` function, for each letter in the string “Mississippi”, print “Letter i of Mississippi is: ” and the letter, where `i` is that letter’s index in the string. When concatenating a string and an integer, don’t forget to cast the integer as a string, as shown in Table 3.

This is  the task and and i tried this code, but it gives me back only `1,2,3,4,5...`

I doubt this is what they want to see.

```
>>> city
'Mississippi'
>>> for i in range(len(city)):
    print("Letter i of Mississippi is : " + city[i], str(i))
```

Comment: The output should be more complex than that - what I get is very different.

Comment: It's preferable to include your code as the content of an editor window, rather than a Python console interaction.

Comment: The reason you are getting so many answers, which differ on minute details, is that you did not provide a sample output, but only an approximation of it. You original code is so close to what you probably need, but you did not specify the latter precisely.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there

```
for i in range(len(city)):
    print("Letter {} of Mississippi is : {}".format(i, city[I]))

    print( "Letter " + str(i) + "...")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate `i` (the variable) into the middle of the string, in place of `i` (the letter).

```
for i in range(len(city)):
    print("Letter " + str(i) + " of Mississippi is: " + city[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print as follows:

```
for i in range(len(city)):
    print(f"Letter {i} of Mississippi is : {city[i]}")
```

Comment: why would he need to - the code he has does what yours does without the need of the f string.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```py
for i in range(len(city)):
    print(f"Letter {city[i]} of Mississippi is at index {str(i)}")
```

```
Letter M of Mississippi is at index 0
Letter i of Mississippi is at index 1
Letter s of Mississippi is at index 2
Letter s of Mississippi is at index 3
Letter i of Mississippi is at index 4
Letter s of Mississippi is at index 5
Letter s of Mississippi is at index 6
Letter i of Mississippi is at index 7
Letter p of Mississippi is at index 8
Letter p of Mississippi is at index 9
Letter i of Mississippi is at index 10
```

**Solution 2** using list comprehension:

```
[f"Letter {city[i]} of Mississippi is at index {str(i)}" for i in range(len(city))]
```

```
['Letter M of Mississippi is at index 0',
 'Letter i of Mississippi is at index 1',
 'Letter s of Mississippi is at index 2',
 'Letter s of Mississippi is at index 3',
 'Letter i of Mississippi is at index 4',
 'Letter s of Mississippi is at index 5',
 'Letter s of Mississippi is at index 6',
 'Letter i of Mississippi is at index 7',
 'Letter p of Mississippi is at index 8',
 'Letter p of Mississippi is at index 9',
 'Letter i of Mississippi is at index 10']
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!